# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE)?

Tags: php

Только пытаюсь изучать PHP. По примеру в книге изучаю ООП
Описывается создание класса и объекта этого класса. Вот код:

```
<? php

 $object = new User;
 print_r($object);


 class User
 {
    public $name, $password;
    function save_user()
    {
        echo "Текст функции Сэйв_юсер";
    }
 }

?>
```

Но при попытке запука этого кода в OpenServer Выдает ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   D:\WebServer\domains\php.learn\index.php on line 3

Но я же все с учебника списывал, почему не работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

На PHP 7 работает. Поробуйте

```
public $name;
public $password;
```

P.S.

```
<? php
```

Заменить на

```
<?php
```

т.е. убрать пробел.

Comment: Да, спасибо, точно, с пробелом не работает!))) Без пробела все заработало!!!

Comment: Отметьте решением, в таком случае :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Что бы работал следующая конструкция  `print_r($object);` нужно добавлять метод __tostring.
2. print_r($object->save_user());
3. Для изучения ООП в PHP рекомендую следующею книгу Зандстра М. - PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования, 4-е издание.

Comment: А лучше просто var_dump($object);